# How to select unique column values all from database using select *?

Tags: java, sql

Create one database:

```
create database TestDemo;
```

Create one table:

```
create table test(rno int(10),name varchar(20),address varchar(20));
```

Insert some values:

```
insert into test values(11,'veeruc','andhra');
insert into test values(12,'veeruc++','tamilnadu');
insert into test values(13,'veerujava','krishna');
insert into test values(14,'veerendra','guntur');
insert into test values(15,'kumar','india');
```

Selecting `rno` related column data:

```
select rno from test;
```

It will display all `rno` column values.

How to write query to get same values using `select *`?

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you intended to use.

Answer (score 1):

To get unique values from database use DISTINCT command (https://www.dofactory.com/sql/select-distinct):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name
```

Unfortunaly, command isn't declare for multiple column.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Select * will return all the fields.

As you mentioned, "select rno from test" returns what you want, why do you want to use select *?

Comment: one of the engineer discussed with me for this doubt i also confused.so finally ur telling not at all possible,i tried this select * from information_schema.COLUMNS where column_name like '%rno%'; but the thing is i am getting all information like schemas.thank you